# Расширить иерархию классов C#

Tags: c#, классы, полиморфизм

Я жестко туплю.. Не могу собрать с мыслями.. Как расширить иерархию классов с использованием виртуального класса в качестве основы иерархии? На основе этого кода:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace StructApp
{
    class Student : Person
    {
        public void Delaet()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Студент идет на учебу ");
        }
    }
    class Prepod
    {
        public string rabotaet;
        public string gde;
        public void Delaet()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Преподователь работает в " + gde);
        }
    }
    class Person
    {
        public string chelovek;
        public string name;
        public void Delaet()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Персона - " + name);
        }
    }
    class Zavkaf : Prepod
    {
        public void Delaet()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Заведующий кафедрой сейчас в " + gde);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Student persona = new Student();
            persona.Delaet();
            Prepod prepod = new Prepod();
            prepod.gde = "Университете ";
            prepod.Delaet();
            Person person = new Person();
            person.name = "Владимир ";
            person.Delaet();
            Zavkaf zavkaf = new Zavkaf();
            zavkaf.gde = "Университете ";
            zavkaf.Delaet();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: виртуальных классов не бывает, есть абстрактные https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/abstract-and-sealed-classes-and-class-members

Comment: что значит `расширить иерархию классов`?

Comment: Цель то какая этого расширения? Что в итоге хотите получить?

Comment: Ну `Person` сделать абстрактным классом. И непонятно ещё, почему препод не человек.

Comment: @CrazyElf: Ну, если двойки ставит, понятно же, что не человек совсем.